# Looping through my CheckBoxList only inserts one record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

The title says my problem - which is that my checkboxes will only insert one record at a time. The modal pops up and I click on 2 checkboxes, yet only one is inserted into my database and displayed on my page. I have to check boxes 1 at a time, and I have many, many checkboxes. Here is the code I have. :) Thanks in advance

```
<!-- Add a Feature -->
    <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="FeatureButton" runat="server">Feature</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Panel ID="FeaturePanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display:none">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbxAddFeature" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsNewFeatures" DataTextField="FeatureTitle" DataValueField="FeatureID"></asp:CheckBoxList>
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitFeatures" runat="server" Text="Submit" /><asp:Button ID="CancelSubmitFeatures" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="FeatureModal" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="CancelSubmitFeatures" DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="FeaturePanel" TargetControlID="FeatureButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    </li>

Protected Sub SubmitFeatures_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitFeatures.Click
  FeatureModal.Hide()
    For Each feature As ListItem In cbxAddFeature.Items
      If feature.Selected Then

       'SQL INSERT: Marketing Table
       Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) VALUES (@ProductID, 3, 'Feature', @MarketingData)"

       Using cn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)

       Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProductID", ProductID.Value))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@MarketingData", feature.Value))

        cn.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
       End Using
End If
Next
 Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

Comment: You subject doesn't contain an actual question. The only thing it says is that you think checkboxes can insert records, which they cannot.

Comment: You shouldn't open/close the sql connection like that. it's a total waste of resources. Open the connection outside of the loop and close it after the loop completes. Worst case, you'll waste a connection if no checkboxes are selected. Otherwise you'll be opening/closing a connection for EVERY checkbox that's selected.

Comment: Do you want to combine multiple inserts statements into one string and execute them in 1 connection?

Comment: @MarcB, I have researched and learned more about SQL injection so I came back to the post and reworded it for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't redirect after the first pass in your loop:

```
For Each feature As ListItem In cbxAddFeature.Items
        If feature.Selected Then
            Dim sqlAddFeatures As String = Nothing
            'SQL INSERT: Marketing Table
            sqlAddFeatures = "INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) VALUES (" & ProductID.Value & ",3, 'Feature', " & feature.Value & ")"
            sqlAddFeatures.Replace("'", "''")
            Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=off-db1;uid=productsDB_admin;pwd=*****;database=Products")
            SqlConnection.Open()
            Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlAddFeatures, SqlConnection)
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SqlConnection.Close()
            'Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) 
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I pulled the response.redirect into the Next and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jlg, you won't be able to insert all the rows in one shot in SQL. You didn't specify what version of SQL you are using, but in SQL Server 2008 you can pass DataTable parameters to a stored procedure and then insert all records at the same time.

This requires that you create a User-Defined Data Type with the exact same structure as your DataTable. [Read here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Or if you don't want to go that route...

[You can at least use transactions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/transactions.aspx)

Comment: It's SQL Server 2008. I don't know basically anything about stored procedures, but the checkboxes seems to be adding multiple records to the database now. :) Thanks for the help